# Search JTree of objects

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

I would really appreciate some help here please.
I'm creating a `JTree` of objects, and I'm currently trying to find an object within the tree and return the path.

Here is my search code:

```
public TreeNode[] searchNode(menuItems nodeS) { //menuItems is they father of all the //objects
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = null;
    Enumeration e = rootNode.breadthFirstEnumeration();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();
      menuItems m = (menuItems)node.getUserObject();
      if (nodeS.equals(m)) {
        return node.getPath();
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is :

1. Go through the tree by using a `Enumeration`
2. for every node get the user object
3. compare the object to my object

My problem: When the search reaches the object I want it does not behave as an object but as a `TreeNode` and therefore the comparison does not work.

This has been driving me crazy all evening, please please help me.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
    if (this == obj) return true; 
    if (obj == null) return false; 
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false; 
    menuItems other = (menuItems) obj; 
    if (id != other.getId()) return false; 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you are comparing nodeS to menuItems, what is object nodeS?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin It the parameter of the method. Based on the type names, they should both be `menuItems` objects (terrible naming).

Comment: nodeS is an object of type menuItems which I receive as an argument.

Comment: oh, didn't see it sorry

Comment: @user3634317 What does your `equals` method look like in the `menuItems` class? By the way, class names should always begin with a capital letter in Java; otherwise it makes it hard to see at a glance what is an object, and what is a type. Also, as you can see, the Stackoverflow syntax highlighter can't properly format it.

Comment: Thank you for the capitals comment, I will take that in to account on future programming.
All "menuItems" have a unique integer id, it compares the two id's.

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj)
   return true;
  if (obj == null)
   return false;
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
   return false;
  menuItems other = (menuItems) obj;
  if (id != other.getId())
   return false;
  return true;
 }

Comment: @user3634317 Ok, thanks. I added the code you pasted to the question for you, but next time just go ahead and edit the question. As you can see, code doesn't get formatted properly in comments. So how did you determine that the object is a `TreeNode`? Also, which object are you referring to, do you mean the `m` variable is the `TreeNode` in the `searchNode` method?

Comment: I'm talking about object m, but that is a good point. I thought it was a TreeNode because In the error it say's: "cannot convert TreeNode". But I just double checked and it also say's: "ClassCastException java.lang.String."

Comment: @user3634317 Ah ok. Do you want to post the full unedited message with the stack trace? I'm slightly confused now because the ClassCastException message doesn't normally (to my recollection) have a portion that says "cannot convert [class]" (meaning this sounds like two different errors).  However, off the bat, if its crapping out on the `m` line, and you're getting that kind of exception, maybe somewhere you've accidentally added a `String` to the user object instead of an actual `menuItems`.